# How can I find in Mathematica if my equation have solution or not on a given interval?

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I'm new to Mathematica. I usually used Wolfram Alpha; however, since the equation that I'm working with is  a long equation I need to use Mathematica. This is an example of the problem. So, I want to know if the equation will have solution or not when `m >= 4` and `n >= 3.41421 m`. I don't know what command to use and when I enter this, it said that `m >= 4` is not a valid variable`. What should I do?

```
Solve[{Binomial[n - 1, 2] - 2[(Binomial[m - 1, 2]) + (n - m)(m - 1) - 1] <= 0}, {m >= 4, n >= 3.41421 m}, Reals]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by the command

```
FindInstance[ Binomial[n - 1, 2] -  2 ((Binomial[m - 1, 2]) + (n - m) (m - 1) - 1) <= 0 &&
 m >= 4 && n >= 3.41421*m, {m, n}, Reals]
   (*{{m -> 537343., n -> 1.8346*10^6}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. It works.